# Question about using system.net.mail

Tags: vb.net

Im getting an error using this code below. I have tried multiple ways and still im getting an error. Any help would be very much appreciated

```
 Dim email As New MailMessage

**Problem:**  email.From.Address = "test@yahoo.com"
 Also tried   email.From.Address.add("test@yahoo.com")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new MailAddress Object.  In C# it is:

email.From = new MailAddress("test@yahoo.com");

Answer (score 1):

The `From` property is of type `MailAddress`, you cannot assign a string to it. Instead, you must construct a new `MailAddress` object from your string and assign it to the `From` property.

... Incidentally, you could have solved this problem by yourself just by *reading the error message* (that you should always report in your questions) and the documentation of the `MailMessage` class.